# Migrate from Godaddy office 365 to have it on Microsoft Outlook itself

Tags: email, outlook, migration, office365, shared-hosting

I am trying to move to Microsoft products totally without any tricky third party management like Godaddy which is giving me hard time. I signed up in Office 365 Business, then opened AdminPortal. tried to add my domain, it gave me this message: **"this domain was already added to a different Office 365 tenant NETORGFT2983960.onmicrosoft.com which is managed by GoDaddy. To add this domain to this tenant you will need to contact GoDaddy support and have this domain removed from NETORGFT2983960.onmicrosoft.com. Once done you can come back and resume this step. Nameservers used: nsXX.domaincontrol.com, nsXX.domaincontrol.com."**

- does that mean I have to cancel my subscription in Goddady and then try to have it on Microsoft?
- if I canceled my old subscription, what will happens to the data in the exiting emails?
- do I have to lose everything in order to complete this procedure? 
  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Microsoft tenant with a Microsoft Partner(ONe that sells all microsoft license or a Gold partner) or microsoft direct. You wont have to deal with the lame login in screen and you will have full admin console rights to exchange online and other services. create the users using the onmicrosoft domain.

The paint full part 
Store all your emails data etc locally or use the microsoft partner to move the data for you on your new tenant.

You will have to get godaddy delete everything from 365 once you are ready.
Then add your domain to the new tenant